# Getting value of inner object field from bundle

Tags: android, bundle

How ca i get value of `imageurl` field from this bundle object?

> Bundle[{x=15300,y=2200, z=Please check!, extra={"
>   imageurl":"url"}, id=0:15341498867878,
>   priority=normal}]

I am getting this bundle through `getIntent().getExtras()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Bundle object and get value by key show in below example

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String a = bundle.getString("imageurl");
```

You will get value in String variable a

Comment: I am getting that bundle in question only through `getIntent().getExtras()`

Comment: Yes, you need to create bundle object then you can get your value from that object, like showing in posted example